# Is there a solution that is not a traveling wave solution for Fisher KPP equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

If there is one, what do they look like? It is better someone explain the following equation $u_t-\Delta u=u(1-u)$.

Comment: What do they look like? What do you mean?

Comment: Like its biological explanation?